# Choosing Between Using an iframe or Hosting on Own Domain for an Embeddable Widget

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget

I'm developing an embeddable widget for integration into various websites, and I'm contemplating between using an iframe or hosting the widget on my own domain. I would like to understand the advantages, disadvantages, suitable use cases, and architectural approaches for each option.

Here are the specific points I would like to explore:

**Advantages and Disadvantages:**

- What are the key advantages of using an iframe to embed the widget within external websites? Are there any limitations or drawbacks to consider?
  On the other hand, what advantages and disadvantages are associated with hosting the widget on my own domain and providing an embed code for websites to include?

**Use Cases:**

- In which scenarios would using an iframe be more suitable for embedding the widget? Are there specific use cases where hosting on my own domain would be preferable?
  How do the different approaches impact factors such as cross-origin communication, security, and customization possibilities for widget users?

**Architectural Approaches:**

- What architectural considerations should I take into account when deciding between an iframe or hosting on my own domain? Are there recommended approaches or design patterns to ensure scalability, maintainability, and performance?

How do the chosen approaches integrate with the overall application architecture, considering aspects such as session management, data sharing, and seamless updates for embedded widgets?

I would greatly appreciate insights, experiences, and recommendations from the community to help me decide whether to use an iframe or host the widget on my domain. Additionally, any best practices or real-world examples regarding architectural approaches would be valuable.

Thank you for your expertise and guidance in advance!